# Is it possible to pass the arguments dynamically instaed of direct values Example: $date.toCalendar(arg) i am getting error

Tags: velocity

Is it possible to pass the arguments dynamically instaed of direct values Example: $date.toCalendar(arg)  i am getting error

Expecting to get the calander obect pasing the dynamic args.

Comment: What is `arg`? What is the error you are getting?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.